# how to implement timeout in java to see whether the response come

Tags: java

I have a two functions, one is the master and the other is the slave. Via master function I'm trying to learn behaviour of the other function. But I should do whatever calculation is a setted time interval. In this part, how can I set a timer, which is marked a boolean variable if timeout occur, and learn whether timeout occurs ?

```
func1   -----send message------>   func2  
             start timer
             if timeout occur, do something else
```

Comment: So essentially, you are trying to create a timeout for the execution of another method?

Comment: @Vulcan yes, I want to implement timeout. If message comes before timeout, cancel the timeout else do other thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concurrent constructs in the JDK. In this case an `ExecutorService` and a `CountDownLatch` is a perfect match:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    final CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(1);
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something here
            System.out.println("working ...");
            ready.countDown();
        }
    });


    boolean timeout = !ready.await(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (timeout) {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
```

Comment: If I thought your code as two part, the first part is doing what, and the second part starting with boolean. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: Can I re-run the timeout ? How ? Can I say that start timeout and finish timeout ?

Comment: Yes. If await(...) returns false, the count hasn't reached zero, and you can try again. You can also test if the count has reached zero. I don't understand the bit about "start timeout and finish timeout".

Comment: I mean by start timeout is I want to use this object several times and I want to restart it from 0. In some part I want to cancel the timeout if I have received a messsage from other func.

Comment: yes, it is what I have look but Is the last question possible ?

Comment: Aha, no you cannot really cancel waiting for the timeout, but if func2 completes "in time", CountDownLatch#await(...) returns true, so this is a kind of signal.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute `func2` in another Thread and let your original Thread [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) with a specified timeout.

Of course you will need to take care of proper synchronization.

Simple example (left out `InteruptedException` handling)

```
void func1(){
    Thread slave = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
             func2();
         }
    });
    slave.start();
    slave.join(100); // waits 100 milliseconds for slave to complete
    if(!slave.isAlive()){
      //slave completed its task
    }else{
      //slave not done yet, do something else
      somethingElse();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't it that if `join` times out, it throws an exception?

Comment: @JanDvorak If join times out it just returns without complaining

Comment: @DeltaLima But the second thread always has to wait 100ms. That is not expected. If the first thread's work done in 5ms, then second thread has to proceed further in 5ms.

Comment: @Ratnakar.class If you use join, the second thread will wait at most 100ms; if the first thread is done after 5ms. The second thread will proceed immediately after the first thread is done. If you want the second thread to wait 100 ms regardless the state of the first thread, use sleep.